# Using sweetalert 2 with custom html and AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, sweetalert2

I am using [SweetAlert2](https://sweetalert2.github.io/) with AngularJS, using this port to AngularJS 1.x : https://github.com/socialbase/angular-sweetalert-2.

I am trying to add some custom html in my swal, so when I do this:

```
angular.module('app').controller('TestController', function($scope, SweetAlert) {
  $scope.test = "My test";

    SweetAlert.swal({
      type: 'warning',
      html: '<input type="text" ng-model="test">'
    }).then(function() {
    });
  });
```

It binds the html correctly, but it isn't binding `ng-model` using my variable `test`. Apparently it is putting the swal modal code outside my `ng-controller` in my html code.

How can I make my variable `test` work with AngularJS and SweetAlert?

Comment: Are you sure, that library supports this feature at all?

Comment: I've looked the https://github.com/socialbase/angular-sweetalert-2 code, and it's just a port for SweetAlert2  to AngularJS 1.x, so I assumed that this library would work with AngularJS inside it, but can be the case it's not supported.

Answer (score 1):

Look at the code for this lib:

https://github.com/socialbase/angular-sweetalert-2/blob/master/lib/angular-sweetalert2.js

As you can see there is very little angular-related "porting", it's just a wrapper to the plain-JS library.

Therefore, it's simply not possible to put in your angular-specific code as a html and expect it to work.

However, looking at this [lib's code examples](https://sweetalert2.github.io/), you could read html input's values after the dialog is closed.

```
angular.module('app').controller('TestController', function($scope, SweetAlert) {
  $scope.test = "My test";

  SweetAlert.swal({
    type: 'warning',
    html: '<input id="swal-input" type="text" ng-model="test">',
    preConfirm: function() {
      return document.getElementById('swal-input').value;
    }
  })
  .then(function(value) {
    $scope.test = value;
  });
});
```

Comment: It was just an example, I need to put an image carousel inside swal.

Comment: @William and I've explained why that could not work and a possible workaround for your question regarding using `ng-model` - if your question is actually different I suggest you create a new one addressing the exact issue (e.g. creating a dialog with a custom angular template bound to a given controller)