# Angular Google map is not displayed when it is placed within sweetalert2 popup

Tags: html, angular, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, sweetalert2

I am trying to display a google map segment is a popup area using sweetalert2. The same HTML code segment provided in the below sweetalert2 function works when it is pasted in the HTML page itself. But not in the alert.

```
export function showGoogleMap() {
    swal({
        title: 'HTML <small>125</small>!',
        html: '<div style="width: 100%; height:500px;"><agm-map style="height: 300px;" [latitude]="51.678418" [longitude]="7.809007">\n' +
        '<agm-marker [latitude]="51.678418" [longitude]="7.809007"></agm-marker></agm-map></div>',
        width: '800px'
    });
}
```

Only an empty area will be displayed there. Check the below image., but not in the alert box. You could see the Map is working in the HTML What is the wrong thing that I am doing here?

[image]

Comment: You should provide a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) that demonstrates the issue. Not just part of your code and a screenshot. You can use a code snippet in your question or create a complete fiddle that demonstrates the problem.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like this library doesn't support angular code in HTML and hence your map inside the alert is not being rendered at all. See [Using sweetalert 2 with custom html and AngularJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50061289/using-sweetalert-2-with-custom-html-and-angularjs)

This may be an alternative https://github.com/sweetalert2/ngx-sweetalert2

Hope this helps!